# Sending FIle with phone line

Tags: c#, .net, tcp

I need to add new items to my application for sending files through phone line with no internet only simple modem.

My main language is C#.

Please help me, I'm stuck with this project for two weeks.

My Application is simple system management and my client want this new item in the new version to send image,worksheet... ext. I make this simple, i say to you the same way they asked me! We want send and receive files in phone line, for example when we want to send data. 
we dial:+9825362307421 in you application and Files should be send to another PC have this phone number (modem attach to this phone line (DSL or Dial Up))

Comment: What did you try yet? Did that include [the xmodem protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) ?

Comment: No, That's a problem,I do not anything about this kind of programming and search internet find nothing that why ask. Can you give me example or PDF,websites anything?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11157536/56778.

Comment: "*modem attach to this phone line (DSL or Dial Up)*" DSL can not "dial numbers", each end will need a regular old fashioned Dial Up modem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to a TAPI tutorial: [TAPI 3.0 Application development using C#.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10994/TAPI-3-0-Application-development-using-C-NET)

Here is a sample application: [Windows TAPI 3 in C#](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/TAPI-3-in-C-Get-Lines-and-dd143eaf)

Comment: Thanks, I like to become expert in this kind of programming, Can you helping me by PDFs,Websites or anything you think can help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this via [TAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms733433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Windows Telephony API). However the wrapper Visual Studio will create for you out of the box [will not work](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841712). Your best option is [3rd party libraries](http://atapi.codeplex.com/) or trying to figure out what Microsoft did in their [example projects](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/TAPI-3-in-C-Get-Lines-and-dd143eaf).

You may also want to look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992073/create-an-application-using-tapi-on-windows-7-where-to-start)  and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333319/net-tapi-interface) for further advice and links you could follow.

Comment: Thanks, I like to become expert in this kind of programming, Can you helping me by PDFs,Websites or anything you think can help me?

Comment: I have never done TAPI myself, just the websites I linked in my answer is what I found via some quick googleing.